# Nav Animation in website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to animate a nav from off-screen to on-screen and vice-versa from the left. I have jquery.min.js on my computer (the latest version) and the nav is not animating from the left. What I did was just the first step: animating the nav once an object is clicked. Here's what I came up with: I uploaded my work to JSFiddle: http://bit.ly/VQIXlF

This is what i have sofar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/Default.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/Script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="menu-open" id="open">Open</h1>
        <div class="nav" id="nav">
            <div class="menu">
                <h1>Menu</h1>
                 <div class="elements">
                    <h2 class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></h2>
                    <h2 class="about"><a href="#">About</a></h2>
                    <h2 class="code"><a href="#">Products</a></h2>
                    <h2 class="design"><a href="#">Contact</a></h2>
                    <h2 class="gaming"><a href="#">Find Us</a></h2>
                    <h2 class="more"><a href="#">More</a></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**jquery:**

```
var main = function(){
    $('.open').click(function(){
        $('.nav').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200);
    });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav{
    top:0;
    left: -300px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:300px;
    background-color: #336ca6;
}
.menu-open{
    position:absolute;
    left:500px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu{
    font-family: arial;
    width:300px;
}
.menu h1{
    position:relative;
    left:100px;
    color: #a0a0a0;
}
.menu h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    width:280px;
}
.menu .elements{
    margin-top:35px;
}
.menu a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
    color:#efefef;
    width:300px;
}
.menu a:hover{
    color:#aaaaaa;
    transition:color 0.5s;
}
.menu .home{
    border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Post your code in the question please.

Comment: You dont actually call your animation function anywhere. You need to have a button with an OnClick attribute. Or have an event handler in your JS. Check out this fiddle it should get you started in the right direction. You still need to figure out how to close the menu though. http://jsfiddle.net/dnu33c8c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the simplest answer is you have used ".open" in your script where open is an id... change

```
$('#open').click(function() /* add the # instead of . */
```

that should work

http://jsfiddle.net/a7fkp785/3/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done more easier by adding a `class` with `css3` transition

```
.nav{
    top:0;
    left: -300px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    height:100%;
    width:300px;
    background-color: #336ca6;
    transition: all 0.5s;/*ADDED*/
}
.slide-nav{
    left:0;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#open').click(function(){
    $('.nav').toggleClass('slide-nav');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a7fkp785/2/)**

Comment: Thanks everybody! This was very helpful! The CSS3 transition is also helpful!